# iOS tests fails in Release but works in Debug

Tags: detox

I just did a small set of tests for my `react-native` app and they work well when testing in `iOS - Debug` mode. But when I try to run it in `iOS - Release` it just fails, saying can't find the components.

I know more information is needed but I have no idea how to actually move forward.
Notes: 
- All `testID` are in `<View />`
- I tried to run with simulator open and the app actually opens
- Did trace and it has no much useful data (but the hierarchy shows no `accessibilityID` or `testID`)

Follows the hierarchy:

```
        Cannot find UI Element.
        Exception with Assertion: {
          "Assertion Criteria":  "assertWithMatcher:matcherForSufficientlyVisible(>=0.750000)",
          "Element Matcher":  "((!(kindOfClass('RCTScrollView')) && (respondsToSelector(accessibilityIdentifier) && accessibilityID('WelcomeScreen_Contents'))) || (((kindOfClass('UIView') || respondsToSelector(accessibilityContainer)) && parentThatMatches(kindOfClass('RCTScrollView'))) && ((kindOfClass('UIView') || respondsToSelector(accessibilityContainer)) && parentThatMatches((respondsToSelector(accessibilityIdentifier) && accessibilityID('WelcomeScreen_Contents'))))))",
          "Recovery Suggestion":  "Check if the element exists in the UI hierarchy printed below. If it exists, adjust the matcher so that it accurately matches element."
        }


        Error Trace: [
          {
            "Description":  "Interaction cannot continue because the desired element was not found.",
            "Error Domain":  "com.google.earlgrey.ElementInteractionErrorDomain",
            "Error Code":  "0",
            "File Name":  "GREYElementInteraction.m",
            "Function Name":  "-[GREYElementInteraction matchedElementsWithTimeout:error:]",
            "Line":  "124"
          }
        ]

        Hierarchy: <UIWindow:0x7fb2a5622f30; AX=N; AX.frame={{0, 0}, {414, 896}}; AX.activationPoint={207, 448}; AX.traits='UIAccessibilityTraitNone'; AX.focused='N'; frame={{0, 0}, {414, 896}}; opaque; alpha=1>
          |--<RCTRootView:0x7fb2a5620e70; AX=N; AX.frame={{0, 0}, {414, 896}}; AX.activationPoint={207, 448}; AX.traits='UIAccessibilityTraitNone'; AX.focused='N'; frame={{0, 0}, {414, 896}}; opaque; alpha=1>
          |  |--<RCTRootContentView:0x7fb2a57c5200; AX=N; AX.label='Welcome! Let's go! Sign in'; AX.frame={{0, 0}, {414, 896}}; AX.activationPoint={207, 448}; AX.traits='UIAccessibilityTraitNone'; AX.focused='N'; frame={{0, 0}, {414, 896}}; opaque; alpha=1>
          |  |  |--<RCTView:0x7fb2a558c7a0; AX=N; AX.label='Welcome! Let's go! Sign in'; AX.frame={{0, 0}, {414, 896}}; AX.activationPoint={207, 448}; AX.traits='UIAccessibilityTraitNone'; AX.focused='N'; frame={{0, 0}, {414, 896}}; opaque; alpha=1>
          |  |  |  |--<RCTView:0x7fb2a55baaf0; AX=N; AX.label='Welcome! Let's go! Sign in'; AX.frame={{0, 0}, {414, 896}}; AX.activationPoint={207, 448}; AX.traits='UIAccessibilityTraitNone'; AX.focused='N'; frame={{0, 0}, {414, 896}}; opaque; alpha=1>
          |  |  |  |  |--<RCTView:0x7fb2a55a6f50; AX=N; AX.label='Welcome! Let's go! Sign in'; AX.frame={{0, 0}, {414, 896}}; AX.activationPoint={207, 448}; AX.traits='UIAccessibilityTraitNone'; AX.focused='N'; frame={{0, 0}, {414, 896}}; opaque; alpha=1>
          |  |  |  |  |  |--<RCTView:0x7fb2a5517b40; AX=N; AX.label='Welcome! Let's go! Sign in'; AX.frame={{0, 0}, {414, 896}}; AX.activationPoint={207, 448}; AX.traits='UIAccessibilityTraitNone'; AX.focused='N'; frame={{0, 0}, {414, 896}}; opaque; alpha=1>
          |  |  |  |  |  |  |--<RCTView:0x7fb2a5791380; AX=N; AX.label='Welcome! Let's go! Sign in'; AX.frame={{0, 0}, {414, 896}}; AX.activationPoint={207, 448}; AX.traits='UIAccessibilityTraitNone'; AX.focused='N'; frame={{0, 0}, {414, 896}}; opaque; alpha=1>
          |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |--<RCTView:0x7fb2a5791070; AX=N; AX.label='Welcome! Let's go! Sign in'; AX.frame={{0, 0}, {414, 896}}; AX.activationPoint={207, 448}; AX.traits='UIAccessibilityTraitNone'; AX.focused='N'; frame={{0, 0}, {414, 896}}; opaque; alpha=1>
          |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |--<RCTView:0x7fb2a5790d60; AX=N; AX.label='Welcome! Let's go! Sign in'; AX.frame={{0, 0}, {414, 896}}; AX.activationPoint={207, 448}; AX.traits='UIAccessibilityTraitNone'; AX.focused='N'; frame={{0, 0}, {414, 896}}; opaque; alpha=1>
          |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |--<RCTView:0x7fb2a5790a50; AX=N; AX.frame={{0, 0}, {414, 88}}; AX.activationPoint={207, 44}; AX.traits='UIAccessibilityTraitNone'; AX.focused='N'; frame={{0, 0}, {414, 88}}; opaque; alpha=1>
          |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |--<RCTView:0x7fb2a5790740; AX=N; AX.frame={{-414, 0}, {414, 88}}; AX.activationPoint={-207, 44}; AX.traits='UIAccessibilityTraitNone'; AX.focused='N'; frame={{-414, 0}, {414, 88}}; opaque; alpha=1>
          |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |--<RCTView:0x7fb2a579d570; AX=N; AX.frame={{-414, 0}, {414, 88}}; AX.activationPoint={-207, 44}; AX.traits='UIAccessibilityTraitNone'; AX.focused='N'; frame={{0, 0}, {414, 88}}; opaque; alpha=1>
          |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |--<RCTView:0x7fb2a579d260; AX=N; AX.frame={{-414, 44}, {414, 43.5}}; AX.activationPoint={-207, 65.75}; AX.traits='UIAccessibilityTraitNone'; AX.focused='N'; frame={{0, 44}, {414, 43.5}}; opaque; alpha=1>
          |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |--<RCTView:0x7fb2a578a1b0; AX=N; AX.label='Welcome! Let's go! Sign in'; AX.frame={{0, 0}, {414, 896}}; AX.activationPoint={207, 448}; AX.traits='UIAccessibilityTraitNone'; AX.focused='N'; frame={{0, 0}, {414, 896}}; opaque; alpha=1>
          |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |--<RCTView:0x7fb2a5593d10; AX=N; AX.label='Welcome! Let's go! Sign in'; AX.frame={{0, 0}, {414, 896}}; AX.activationPoint={207, 448}; AX.traits='UIAccessibilityTraitNone'; AX.focused='N'; frame={{0, 0}, {414, 896}}; opaque; alpha=1>
          |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |--<RCTView:0x7fb2a55a5c90; AX=N; AX.label='Welcome! Let's go! Sign in'; AX.frame={{0, 0}, {414, 896}}; AX.activationPoint={207, 448}; AX.traits='UIAccessibilityTraitNone'; AX.focused='N'; frame={{0, 0}, {414, 896}}; opaque; alpha=1>
          |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |--<RCTView:0x7fb2a55d0c60; AX=N; AX.label='Welcome! Let's go! Sign in'; AX.frame={{0, 0}, {414, 896}}; AX.activationPoint={207, 448}; AX.traits='UIAccessibilityTraitNone'; AX.focused='N'; frame={{0, 0}, {414, 896}}; opaque; alpha=1>
          |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |--<RCTView:0x7fb2a55d92f0; AX=N; AX.label='Welcome! Let's go! Sign in'; AX.frame={{0, 44}, {414, 818}}; AX.activationPoint={207, 453}; AX.traits='UIAccessibilityTraitNone'; AX.focused='N'; frame={{0, 44}, {414, 818}}; opaque; alpha=1>
          |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |--<RCTView:0x7fb2a55d0950; AX=N; AX.label='Sign in'; AX.frame={{0, 816}, {414, 36}}; AX.activationPoint={207, 834}; AX.traits='UIAccessibilityTraitNone'; AX.focused='N'; frame={{0, 772}, {414, 36}}; opaque; alpha=1>
          |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |--<RCTView:0x7fb2a55cd670; AX=Y; AX.id='Touchable'; AX.label='Sign in'; AX.frame={{0, 816}, {414, 36}}; AX.activationPoint={207, 834}; AX.traits='UIAccessibilityTraitNone'; AX.focused='N'; frame={{0, 0}, {414, 36}}; opaque; alpha=1>
          |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |--<RCTTextView:0x7fb2a55b3040; AX=Y; AX.label='Sign in'; AX.frame={{0, 816}, {414, 36.5}}; AX.activationPoint={207, 834.25}; AX.traits='UIAccessibilityTraitStaticText'; AX.focused='N'; frame={{0, 0}, {414, 36.5}}; alpha=1>
          |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |--<RCTView:0x7fb2a55cd360; AX=N; AX.label='Welcome! Let's go!'; AX.frame={{0, 44}, {414, 772}}; AX.activationPoint={207, 430}; AX.traits='UIAccessibilityTraitNone'; AX.focused='N'; frame={{0, 0}, {414, 772}}; opaque; alpha=1>
          |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |--<RCTView:0x7fb2a55cd050; AX=N; AX.frame={{207, 500}, {0, 316}}; AX.activationPoint={207, 658}; AX.traits='UIAccessibilityTraitNone'; AX.focused='N'; frame={{207, 456}, {0, 316}}; opaque; alpha=1>
          |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |--<RCTView:0x7fb2a55ccd40; AX=N; AX.label='Let's go!'; AX.frame={{147, 460}, {120, 40}}; AX.activationPoint={207, 480}; AX.traits='UIAccessibilityTraitNone'; AX.focused='N'; frame={{147, 416}, {120, 40}}; opaque; alpha=1>
          |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |--<RCTView:0x7fb2a55cca30; AX=Y; AX.id='Touchable'; AX.label='Let's go!'; AX.frame={{147, 460}, {120, 40}}; AX.activationPoint={207, 480}; AX.traits='UIAccessibilityTraitNone'; AX.focused='N'; frame={{0, 0}, {120, 40}}; opaque; alpha=1>
          |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |--<RCTTextView:0x7fb2a55cc800; AX=Y; AX.label='Let's go!'; AX.frame={{164, 471}, {86, 18.5}}; AX.activationPoint={207, 480.25}; AX.traits='UIAccessibilityTraitStaticText'; AX.focused='N'; frame={{17, 11}, {86, 18.5}}; alpha=1>
          |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |--<RCTTextView:0x7fb2a55cc210; AX=Y; AX.label='Answer two quick questions to get started.'; AX.frame={{68, 379.5}, {278, 50.5}}; AX.activationPoint={207, 404.75}; AX.traits='UIAccessibilityTraitStaticText'; AX.focused='N'; frame={{68, 335.5}, {278, 50.5}}; alpha=1>
          |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |--<RCTView:0x7fb2a55cbd20; AX=N; AX.label='Welcome to '; AX.frame={{97.5, 44}, {219, 336}}; AX.activationPoint={207, 212}; AX.traits='UIAccessibilityTraitNone'; AX.focused='N'; frame={{97.5, 0}, {219, 336}}; opaque; alpha=1>
          |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |--<RCTView:0x7fb2a55cba10; AX=N; AX.label='Welcome to '; AX.frame={{97.5, 327}, {219, 33}}; AX.activationPoint={207, 343.5}; AX.traits='UIAccessibilityTraitNone'; AX.focused='N'; frame={{0, 283}, {219, 33}}; opaque; alpha=1>
          |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |--<RCTImageView:0x7fb2a55cb730; AX=N; AX.id='/Users/.../Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4FF22CAE-8C08-4FA8-8CB7-DEC31EB77737/data/Containers/Data/Application/608DC539-4BB6-4C2D-934E-98C4863ED4D1/Library/Application Support/CodePush/76158f1b9b351e2881c905cc31e6f30ea33a2e52829f92e0b092dcc45be9cfde/CodePush/assets/app/assets/images/logo@2x.png'; AX.frame={{258.5, 333}, {58, 21}}; AX.activationPoint={287.5, 343.5}; AX.traits='UIAccessibilityTraitImage'; AX.focused='N'; frame={{161, 6}, {58, 21}}; alpha=1>
          |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |--<RCTTextView:0x7fb2a55cb500; AX=Y; AX.label='Welcome to '; AX.frame={{97.5, 327}, {162, 33.5}}; AX.activationPoint={178.5, 343.75}; AX.traits='UIAccessibilityTraitStaticText'; AX.focused='N'; frame={{0, 0}, {162, 33.5}}; alpha=1>

           9 |
          10 |   it('WelcomeScreen: Loaded', async () => {
        > 11 |     await expect(element(by.id('WelcomeScreen_Contents'))).toBeVisible();
             |                                                            ^
          12 |   });
```

I also tried some other values:

```html
        <View
          style={styles.contents}
          testID="WelcomeScreen_Contents1"
          accessibilityHint="WelcomeScreen_Contents2"
          accessibilityLabel="WelcomeScreen_Contents3"
        >
```

And the following tests:

```js
  it('WelcomeScreen: Loaded 1', async () => {
    await expect(element(by.id('WelcomeScreen_Contents1'))).toBeVisible();
  });

  it('WelcomeScreen: Loaded 2', async () => {
    await expect(element(by.id('WelcomeScreen_Contents2'))).toBeVisible();
  });

  it('WelcomeScreen: Loaded 3', async () => {
    await expect(element(by.id('WelcomeScreen_Contents3'))).toBeVisible();
  });
```

Detox config at package.json

```
  "detox": {
    "configurations": {
      "iphonexr": {
        "binaryPath": "ios/build/xxx/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/xxx.app",
        "build": "RCT_NO_LAUNCH_PACKAGER=1 xcodebuild -quiet -workspace ios/xxx.xcworkspace -UseNewBuildSystem=NO -configuration Release -scheme xxx -derivedDataPath ios/build/xxx -sdk iphonesimulator",
        "type": "ios.simulator",
        "name": "iPhone Xʀ"
      },
      "iphonese": {
        "binaryPath": "ios/build/xxx/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/xxx.app",
        "build": "RCT_NO_LAUNCH_PACKAGER=1 xcodebuild -quiet -workspace ios/xxx.xcworkspace -UseNewBuildSystem=NO -configuration Release -scheme xxx -derivedDataPath ios/build/xxx -sdk iphonesimulator",
        "type": "ios.simulator",
        "name": "iPhone SE"
      }
    },
    "test-runner": "jest"
  }
  }
```

Comment: can you share your detox configurations from package.json ?

Comment: @vk.4884 sorry the delay, just updated the information. The problem seems to be a little intermittent...

Comment: It's weird because I tried "by.label" too and it also fails!

Comment: Take a look at your hierarchy. None of the accessibility values exist there. That means that either they are being optimized out by RN or somehow you have a bug in the app.

Comment: @LeoNatan I wonder if I'm using some sort of flag that actually clean them up

Comment: Could be also that RN is doing some view flattening: https://twitter.com/shergin/status/1058393187079704576

A "view" is not something you would normally test for. Perhaps try testing the content, rather than the wrapper view.

Comment: The views I'm testing actually do some layout... still trying to find when exactly it stops working

Comment: The problem seems to be related to View Flattening indeed... But even adding a lot of extra A11Y labels and IDs, in many components, RN seems to actually ignore them! One example is <Image /> that ignores my testID and picks the image name instead...

Comment: @LeoNatan, maybe you want to add this one to the docs as a Troubleshooting: It was CodePush!!! Please, feel free to answer my question so I can properly reward you.

Comment: Detox docs are not meant to be app developer support, especially for non-standard features. You can answer the question and I’ll upvote.

Answer (score 3):

After hours of debugging I found out the problems were:
- CodePush overriding my changes
- RN's View Flattening ( https://twitter.com/shergin/status/1058393187079704576 )

I added a small check so I can disable CodePush for Test builds and it works properly now.

Comment: Be aware that Apple has been cracking down from time to time on apps using CodePush and similar technologies. I'd recommend transitioning out of using it.

Comment: @LeoNatan I'm not sure where you got that information but it is incorrect. CodePush and other interpreted code deployment technologies are explicitly allowed by section 3.3.2 of Apple's developer agreement.

Comment: Could you post your small check and how you disabled codepush for test builds?

Comment: I've created a `CodePushify` component. And on E2E it doesn't add the CodePush. @BoKKeR